# Transformers pretraining with MLM problem - sentence embeddings

Tags: pytorch, torch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, sentence-transformers

Im pretraining trasformer with my own unlabeled data like this:

`python train_mlm.py sentence-transformers/LaBSE train.txt`
Based on https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/tree/master/examples/unsupervised_learning/MLM

Then I want to get embeddings for setnences. Code:

```
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('output/sentence-transformers_LaBSE-2021-12-28_13-03-20')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('output/sentence-transformers_LaBSE-2021-12-28_13-03-20')

model = model.eval()

english_sentences = [
    "dog",
    "Puppies are nice.",
    "I enjoy taking long walks along the beach with my dog.",
]
encoded_input = tokenizer(english_sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=64, return_tensors='pt')
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input)

print(model_output[0].shape)
```

Problem is that shape of my output is someting like (3, 14, 500 000).
When without training on my data shape is (3, 14, 768). What I have done wrong? How can I get final embeddings after my training?

Answer (score 0):

You pre-trained a transformer on Masked Language Modeling (MLM). That does not mean you have to use the MLM head afterwards: `AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained`; because your downstream task is actually embedding generation given some inputs. This is achieved by only using the base encoder of your fine-tuned model, without any head on top: `AutoModel.from_pretrained(...)`. This will return the output shapes you are expecting.

More clarification on the output shapes you are getting:

- (B, L, 768) is the expected output of running a Transformer encoder without heads, i.e. as a generator of embeddings. This is because 768 is the usual hidden-layer size of Transformer encoders. This is what `AutoModel` provides.
- (B, L, 500000) is the expected output of running a Transformer encoder with a MLM head on top, i.e. as a predictor of masked tokens in a MLM task. Something like 500000 is the vocabulary size, and the logits predicted indicate which vocabulary token is more likely to fill the gap. This is what `AutoModelForMaskedLM` provides.

Given B = batch size and L = batch sequence length.

Comment: what do you mean? if someone has trained model with AutoModelForMaskedLM and then saved it how could he read it with AutoModel afterwards? how do you save AutoModelForMaskedLM? torch.save?

Comment: If you save your HuggingFace model with `model.save_pretrained()` and `model` was an instance of `AutoModelForMaskedLM`, you can later run both `AutoModel.from_pretrained()` and `AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained()` on it and load, respectively, the 2 cases I specify in the answer. The reason for that is that this is how transfer learning for BERT-like architectures works: there is a common, pre-trained encoder part to which a head for a downstream task can be attached. The HuggingFace commands for loading/saving I meant are aware of this and allow you to just load the encoder if needed.